# way to do subtraction between two text files in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I've two big files, a.txt and b.txt

each contains a lot of entries like this:

say a.txt has these:

```
12 entry1  
23 entry2  
34 entry4  
...
```

b.txt has these:

```
14 entry1  
25 entry3  
14 entry4  
...
```

how can I do the subtraction for the same entry, while leaving the uniq entries untouched? e.g.

a.txt - b.txt would give me

```
entry1: 12-14 = -2  
entry2: 23  
entry3:    25  
entry4: 34-14 = 20  
...
```

I couldn't figure it out, please help.
I know awk should be the way to go, but just cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: check out awk, its quite delightful

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. It's basically "I need a program to do X".

Comment: Use awk. When it's reading the first file, it creates an array whose keys are the second column, and values are they first column. When it's reading the second array, it subtracts the first column from the corresponding entries in the array. Then  at the end it prints all the values from the array.

Comment: There are many `awk` tutorials and examples that should show how to tell whether you're reading the first or second input file.

Comment: If you say "but just cannot figure it out", then please edit your question to include your best attempt to solve your problem. Then we can help you not only get a solution to your problem, but help you improve your understanding of how awk works. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll paste my best attempt here soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version without awk, it could help you while you finish your awk script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#substraction.sh
file1="a.txt"
file2="b.txt"
echo "">myTempFile.txt
fileTemp="myTempFile.txt"

lin1=$(wc -l $file1 | cut -d " " -f 1)
lin2=$(wc -l $file2 | cut -d " " -f 1)

if [ $lin1 -lt $lin2 ]; then
    lineas=$lin2
    myfileBIG=$file2
    myfileTINY=$file1
else
    lineas=$lin1
    myfileBIG=$file1
    myfileTINY=$file2
fi

ind=1

echo "Total of lines: "$lineas
#### myfileBIG with myfileTINY
while [ $ind -le $lineas ] #less than or equal to
    do
        mynum1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileBIG | cut -d " " -f 1)
        mydat1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileBIG | cut -d " " -f 2)
        mynum2=$(cat $myfileTINY | grep $mydat1 | cut -d " " -f 1)
#echo "$mynum1**$mydat1**$mynum2"
        if [ -n "$mynum2" ]; then
            result=$(($mynum1-$mynum2))
            echo "$mydat1: $mynum1-$mynum2=$result"
            echo "$mydat1: $mynum1-$mynum2=$result">>myTempFile.txt
        else
            result=""
            echo "$mydat1: $mynum1"
            echo "$mydat1: $mynum1">>myTempFile.txt
        fi

        ind=$(($ind+1))
        #echo "Posicion: $ind de $lineas"
    done

#### myfileTINY with myTempFile
echo "Using temp file..."
ind=1
if [ $lineas -eq $lin1 ]; then
    lineas=$lin2
else
    lineas=$lin1
fi
echo "Total of lines: "$lineas

while [ $ind -le $lineas ]
    do
        mynum1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileTINY | cut -d " " -f 1)
        mydat1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileTINY | cut -d " " -f 2)
        mynum2=$(cat $fileTemp | grep $mydat1 | cut -d " " -f 1)
#echo "$mynum1**$mydat1**$mynum2"
        if [ -z "$mynum2" ]; then
            echo "$mydat1:    $mynum1"
            echo "$mydat1:    $mynum1">>myTempFile.txt
        fi

        ind=$(($ind+1))
        #echo "Posicion: $ind de $lineas"
    done
echo "...Done!"
echo "Result:"
sort -b myTempFile.txt
```

Execute follow this:

```
bash ./substraction.sh
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your work, but it didn't actually work for me, I opened the myTempFile.txt that gets generated but found only lines of colon, nothing else.

Comment: Do you have a.txt and b.txt files in the same directory as the file substraction.sh?

Comment: @SSun Did you get some error message? At first line a.txt "12 entry" is separated by space or tab? I tested in my pc and it works!, I will edit my post and will upload a img.

Comment: Yes, sure, absolutely, I've both a.txt and b.text in the same directory as this script is in. It's separated by a space. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: excute `sed -n 1p b.txt | cut -d " " -f 1` and tell me your output

Comment: Sorry for the delay. And it was actually a tab between the two fields, so I executed this line:     `sed -n 1p b.txt | cut -d $'\t' -f1`, and it returns me this result: `14 entry1` as expected. thanks a lot for your help again!

Comment: if your file have a space between the two fields, the command `sed -n 1p b.txt | cut -d " " -f 1` had returned `14`, only one field. And if it's separated by a tab, you will get the same output executing `sed -n 1p b.txt | cut  -f 1`, because `cut` use a TAB as field delimiter default. Therefore, you must delete `-d " "`, all of them.

Comment: @SSun i.e, you must write `mynum1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileTINY | cut  -f 1)` instead of `mynum1=$(sed -n "$ind"p $myfileTINY | cut -d " " -f 1)`

Comment: thanks, but I did try with this command: `sed -n 1 b.txt | cut -f 1`, it's still returning me `14 entry1`.

Comment: It must be `sed -n 1p b.txt | cut -f 1` @SSun